# View: Only display parent term?

Tags: views

I'm trying to create a view that will display a number of nodes sorted by their parent terms.

For instance, if my terms have the following hierarchy:

```
- Fruit
--Apple
--Banana
--Orange
-Vegetable
--Broccoli
--Carrot
--Beet
```

I would ideally like to get two 'headings', one for Fruit, one for Vegetables and then list nodes with any sub-term in those sections.

I have tried using view relationships and contextual filters but I just feel lost. What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Filter by parent term = null

Comment: @ar7max Your answer is for a `contextual filter` correct?

Comment: Hi, Vecta. Are these filtered (e.g. mypage/fruit displays nodes in the fruit group) or are you looking for an expansive, grouped list?

Comment: @othermachines I'd like it to be an expansive list of the parent categories available—a list someone could view to see that they could view "Fruits" or "Vegetables" and then navigate further into the site.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your view settings. Add term relationship - your term field. Add Filter critera - Parent term. Operator 'equal' value - leave empty
[image: parent]

Answer (score 1):

You first need to relate the child term to the parent, and then use the grouping feature to group nodes by the parent term.

The tricky part about this is that it only works to a depth of 2. If a term is a parent *at any depth* it will be added to the group. To explain, in the example below "apples" would also be considered a parent and so you would end up with an "apples" group in addition to fruit and vegetables. (If anyone out there knows how to limit the grouping of parents by depth, leave a comment.)

*This won't work:*

> fruit
>   - - bananas
>   - - apples
>   - - - - granny smith
>   - - - - macintosh
>   vegetables
>   - - carrots

*This works:*

> fruit
>   - - bananas
>   - - apples
>   - - oranges
>   vegetables
>   - - carrots

#### View Set-up

**Relationships**

*Content: Taxonomy terms on node*

```
             Vocabularies .. [select]
               Identifier .. "child"
```

*Taxonomy term: Parent term*

```
             Relationship .. child
               Identifier .. "parent"
Require this relationship .. [checked]
```

**Fields**

*Content: Title*

```
No special settings
```

*Taxonomy Term: Name*

```
             Relationship .. parent
     Exclude from display .. [checked]
```

**Format**

*Format: Settings*

```
      Grouping field Nr.1 .. (parent) Taxonomy Term: Name
```

**Query settings (Other)**

```
                 Distinct .. [checked]
```

*Note: The above settings reduces duplicates. If for some reason this causes issues or you're looking for more fine-grained control, use Aggregation (under "Other").*

Hope that helps!